# Parse php json(no key) to Java

Tags: java, json

I got json data:

```
[["13021031","icon_nopic.png"]]
```

It has no "key".

I have tried multiple variations of this, include Gson,but none of them seem to work because I think the json I got didn't have a key.Is there a good solution to the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a list of lists, according to the sqare brackets.

Comment: To validate a JSON you can use some service: https://jsonlint.com/, if you try you will see that is valid

Comment: Please provide more information about how you try to decode it and what error you have.

Comment: As @Mario told you , try to work with it as list not JSON

Comment: According to  data I got,I do not know how to create entity class

Comment: @BellaHe you don't need an entity class, you should be able to parse the string as a type List<List<Object>> and then assign it to a variable and work with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<List<String>> arr = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<List<String>>>(){}.getType());
```